# Tippecanoe to not hide geometry

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mbtiles, mapbox-studio, tippecanoe

I use these options to create mbtiles for mapbox `--accumulate-attribute` to accumulate `population` from polygons, so I can get population with `mapbox.queryRenderedFeatures` in bbox

```
tippecanoe -o out_sum.mbtiles -P --coalesce-smallest-as-needed --detect-shared-borders --extend-zooms-if-still-dropping -z12 --accumulate-attribute=population_c:sum joined_output_z_F.geojson
```

but at small zoom levels like 1-2-3-4-5, some of the geometry is dropped.

Is it possible somehow to not drop geometry that accumulate-attribute?

I need the geometry(that accumulate-attribute population_c) visible at all zoom levels.

Answer (score 1):

Use the flag `-r1`.

`-r` stands for the rate at which geometries are dropped (default: 2.5). According to the docs, `-r1` is used to

> not automatically drop a fraction of points at low zoom levels

[Source](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#clustered-points-world-cities-summing-the-clustered-population-visible-at-all-zoom-levels)

PS.: `tippecanoe` seems not to be under active development. Going forward, you might have a look into the [GDAL/OGR MBTiles driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html)